# Query between two ACF Date Fields in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, date, datetime, elementor

I am trying to query for an event if the current date is between (inclusive) the start date and end date set by ACF. The return value format for my ACF field is Ymd as well. Here's what I have so far...

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/now_playing', function( $query ) {
    // Set the custom post type 
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'shows' ] ); 

    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    } 

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[]=[
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'compare' => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end_date',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'compare' => '>='
            ),       
        ];
 } );
```

Currently, I am not getting any results, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Whenever I'm doing greater-than or less-than comparisons and I'm not getting the expected results, I flip the comparisons (change greater-than to less-than) as it can be difficult to tell which side each value is on. Have you tried flipping the comparison operators?

Comment: @Caleb, funnily enough, yes. Before posting about this issue, that was actually the first thing I did and still nothing.

Comment: Can you please add a list of all the metadata for one of the shows you expect in the query results? You can use [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) to retrieve an array of all metadata.

Comment: Also try removing the meta query code, to confirm that the adjustment to your post type is working.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the usage of get_metadata(), how can I use it?
I have removed the meta_query and see all the shows. I am not sure why, but now I am seeing results after adding the meta_query back, but it's not the expected results, it is currently showing ALL shows rather than the show that is currently playing.

Comment: The function's documentation that I linked should be sufficient for how to use it.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1686166658:2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 63 ) 
Array ( [0] => field_6475246654c06 ) 
Array ( [0] => #373231 ) 
Array ( [0] => field_647527b288b99 ) 
Array ( [0] => 107 ) 
Array ( [0] => field_64752ff1d25c6 ) 
Array ( [0] => 20230605 ) 
Array ( [0] => field_64763bdec8ed3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 20231105 ) 
Array ( [0] => field_64763bf8c8ed4 ) 
Array ( [0] => ) 
Array ( [0] => field_6479112e8875b ) 
Array ( [0] => ) 
Array ( [0] => field_647e137d4e095 ) 
Array ( [0] => ) 
Array ( [0] => field_647e142c4e098 )

Comment: Hmm, that's not the output I expected (I should've requested `get_post_meta( $post_id )`), but it looks like we may have uncovered the issue: the format of the dates does not include dashes.

Comment: So perhaps my solution is changing the 'value' => date('Y-m-d') to a string format?

Comment: Possibly, and removing the dashes. I don’t know what that will do for the comparison though.

Comment: I was able to get it working see my answer below. Thanks for helping out, seeing the date format was incorrect was a huge factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by setting the date format of value to `current_time('Ymd')`. Additionally, it looks like I had forgotten to set the query after appending the meta query.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/now_playing', function( $query ) {
    $today = current_time('Ymd');
    // Set the custom post type 
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'shows' ] ); 

    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    } 

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[]=[
        array (
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        array (
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>=',
        )
    ];
    
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
 } );
```